# Linux: install pip packages using xcopy

Tags: python, pip, jupyter, xcopy

I am looking for help to install pip packages using xcopy.
I am running a container, in which i need to bring up jupyter. I do not own the container docker file. So when container comes up, i want to copy jupyter binaries from hosted filesystem inside cotainer.
Can someone share how to demystify pip package installation. So I can mount these files correctly to make it work ?

Comment: Why can't you just run `pip`?

Comment: pip will take few min to install. For every container which comes and goes, this add up some time. Also I am look for a way to mount and run these pip installation from host file system, to improve get go time

Comment: Also jupyter is one example, i have several pip installs

Comment: You cannot write another docker file with base as the current one and add pip to it ?

Comment: You can also mount a directory into a container. Just for retrospective, look at your question: You're asking how to do "X for Y". That's a bad approach, rather say "How do I do Y?" Maybe add "I have looked at X, but had following issues with it: ...". That's a much better approach. BTW: Take a look at the description of the "xcopy" tag, you'll be surprised!